# Error when I use TranslateHttpLoader in Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, http, typescript

I am developing application with angular4.
Now I am developing l

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    let fullLocationPath = location.host + location.pathname;
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, fullLocationPath + 'assets/languages/', '.json');
}
```

But I got next error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:4200/assets/languages/en.json.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

How can I fix IT?

Comment: I guess you are 'developing' locally in the file system. What's the url of the application you have in the browser?

Comment: URL - localhost:4200

Comment: while running the application or opening the build file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see in the code where you use the `fullLocationPath`, but you need to add `location.protocol` in front of it, or better, use `location.origin`:

```
let fullLocationPath = location.origin + location.pathname;
```